# Trying to add a google map api to my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, maps

Can someone help me out and tell me why my map isn't appearing at all on the page even after I've added my API key? What Have I written wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/hute2o63/3/

```
<h3>MY Demo Map</h3>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Your javascript is missing `,`s and you should put the script tag in your html

Comment: well <script> tags should not be in the script block...

Comment: still, https://jsfiddle.net/hute2o63/3/

Answer (score 1):

Below is what you are going to want to have to get your map working :)

Depending on what you're trying to achieve can vary in what you need to have on your page.

HTML:

```
<h3>MY Demo Map</h3>
<div id="canvas-map"></div>
<script>
  function initMap() {
    var uluru = {lat: 0, lng: 0};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('canvas-map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: uluru
    });
  }
</script>

<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

CSS:

```
#canvas-map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Here is the link on how to create your Map as well: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map

Good luck and Happy coding :)